# Prove that $\frac{c^{n+1}-1}{c-1}$ = $\Theta(c^n)$, for every $c > 1$

Tags: proof-verification, asymptotics

I am trying to prove that $\frac{c^{n+1}-1}{c-1}$ = $\Theta(c^n)$ for positive real number c > 1.

This is how I approached the problem:

I want to find 2 constants $k_{1}$ and $k_{2}$ such that
$k_{1}c^n \le \frac{c^{n+1}-1}{c-1} \le k_{2}c^n$

Dividing all sides by $c^n$ gives:

$k_{1} \le \frac{c^{n+1}-1}{c^{n+1}-c^n} \le k_{2}$

The numerator is greater than the denominator here, or if I plug in numbers like n = 1, n = 2, ... for any c > 1, I will find the bounds $k_{1}$ = 1 and $k_{2}$ = 2.

I am not sure if my proof is correct or I am missing anything.

Comment: I am not convinced by "I will find the bounds..." They may be correct, but you have not proved it.

Comment: Hint: $\sum_\limits{i=0}^n c^i =\ ?$

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe that actually came from the original problem. I wrote it out like above

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe Hint to what?

Comment: $$k_1=1\qquad k_2=\frac{c}{c-1}$$

Comment: @Did when I first looked at your solution I thought you meant $k_{2}$ is $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c^n$ but I double checked and I was wrong
How did you get $\frac{c}{c-1}$

Comment: @PTN Let me suggest that you try to show that $$\frac{c^{n+1}-1}{c-1} \leqslant\frac{c}{c-1}\cdot c^n$$ for every $n$, I am sure you can succeed.

Comment: @Did That's all I need. Thanks so much